# How to distribute uploaded files to Users attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, dropbox-api

Okay, I'm a little new at this; but I really don't know how to go about doing this:

I have an assets model, an articles model, and a user model.

The assets model has a paperclip document attribute.

```
#asset.rb
belongs_to :article
has_attached_file :document, 
  :path => "assets/:id-:basename-:style.:extension",
  storage: :dropbox,
  dropbox_credentials: Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml")
validates_attachment :document, content_type: { content_type: "application/pdf" }



#article.rb
belongs_to :user
has_many :assets, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => lambda { |d| d[:document].blank? }
validates :title, :content, presence: true

#articles_controller.rb
def new
  @article = Article.new
  @article.assets.build
end
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :content,
    assets_attributes: [:id, :article_id, :document, :_destroy]
  )
end



#user.rb
has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
has_many :assets, through: :articles
REGEX_EMAIL = /\A([\w+\-.]+)(@[\w+\-.]+)(\.[a-z]+)\z/i
validates :email, format: { with: REGEX_EMAIL }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
has_secure_password
validates :dp_key, :dp_secret, presence: true



#config/dropbox.yml
app_key: "r3g00ca3v1hfwjj"
app_secret: "dkixp9rgqkkyflma"
access_token: "13dn69hab311ij35"
access_token_secret: "hq1jniuyjpa791y"
user_id: "14864638"
access_type: "app_folder"
```

Each user has an attribute for their dropbox apikey. What I want to do is whenever they upload a document asset, I want the asset model to use the user's API key rather than the default one if the user doesn't have a saved drop apikey.

I am assuming I need to pass some variables from the controller to the model?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Would probably be more helpful if you would add the attributes for each of your models. Sounds like you just need to pass variables around from one controller to another. Check out using hidden fields to do that.

Comment: Hi, @Lumbee I updated the models with more information. Let me know if I need to provide more. And thank you for your help.

Comment: OK, post your code you are using to interact with dropbox. Specifically the varibles with the API keys that you are passing to dropbox.

Comment: Updated.  FYI - Those keys are outdated.

Comment: Can you successfully talk to the dropbox api using default keys rather than specific user keys? If so, that is the code I want to see. Then I can walk you through substituting the default keys with specific user keys.

Comment: Yes, this works completely with my default keys that I set in the model (dropbox.yml). I just don't know how to access the current user's keys in the model rather than the default keys.

Comment: So you should have some code (controller or model) that accesses those keys in dropbox.yml, and sends that up to dropbox. Show us that code. That is where you would want to substitute the default keys with the users keys. I think we may be losing something in communication here. Another option would be to throw a gist (or the entire app) in github so we are seeing all your code.

Comment: @Lumbee, here's the repo: https://github.com/nguyenj/rails-dropbox

Comment: So are you using this gem https://github.com/riscfuture/dropbox? Looks like you will need the code in the example "Tutorial by Example, Rails Edition". The way you have this app configured (and using the dropbox.yml, the app is initialized with those specific credentials, and there is not going to be a way to change them. Also check out http://tomash.wrug.eu/blog/2012/09/04/integrating-with-dropbox-api-for-fun-and-profit/. You need a way to get the users DB credentials and authenticate via the DB api.

Comment: Thanks @Lumbee this seems very promising.

Comment: Actually, I think I do achieve this using the `Proc.new` for `dropbox_credentials:` to define the credentials at runtime.